# Studying and understanding how Google AdSense works behind the scenes

Tags: javascript, iframe, adsense

I would like to learn how Google AdSense works in the sense of understanding for an example how that javascript we put on a page loads an iframe (is it an iframe ?) which checks the words on a page and then sends those words and gets back some ads. Does anyone know any good tutorials on this ? I'm not interested in knowing how to use google adsense or what's the logic behind it (so [this](http://kpfingaz.hubpages.com/hub/How_does_Google_Adsense_work) and [this](http://www.google.com/support/adsense/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=29574) do not answer my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the JavaScript does send back the page contents. I believe that they use a separate crawler (different to their Google Search crawler) that scans your pages for keywords. When AdSense is added to a page it tells Google the URL and then the crawler scans the page later. That is why there is a delay between putting the AdSense on the page, and getting relevant adverts.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Do you happen to know how the javascript sends that url to google's server ? What do they use for message passing ?

Comment: They don't need the JavaScript to send the URL. When the script is loaded from Google's server the referring URL is automatically sent to them as part of the HTTP request.

Comment: Thank you, I finally understand more or less what happens behind AdSense :)